# Merge dicts from list with getting set of values for equal keys

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.10

Do I have any opportunity to rewrite the code below with dict enhancement? (if I name it right, mean `{k: v for k, v in ...}`)

```py
list_of_dicts = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'b': 20, 'c': 3}, {'a': 10, 'b': 2}]
for k, v in [p for d in list_of_dicts  for p in d.items()]:
    d[k] = d.setdefault(k, set()) | {v}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure why not :). but it is nested at bit

```
import itertools
list_of_dicts = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'b': 20, 'c': 3}, {'a': 10, 'b': 2}]
o = {k: {d[k] for d in list_of_dicts if k in d} for k in itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_of_dicts)}
print(o)
```

Comment: That's nice and clear. Thanks, man!